Boundary Scan over DAP with Lauterbach Power Debugger
I am currently working on a university project where I need to run a Boundary Scan on my Infineon TriBoard TC367DP V 2.0 using the Lauterbach Power Debug interface and Trace32. As I am relatively new to embedded debugging, I've got hummbled pretty fast with this project.
I came across a PDF from Lauterbach that explained how to perform a Boundary Scan using JTAG.
However, my debug interface is connected via DAP, not JTAG.
So far, I've managed to successfully run some demo scripts on the board, which suggests that my setup is correct.
I have also loaded the BSDL file.
When I attempt to run the scan, I encounter a warning that states: "TRACE32 RemoteAPI cannot handle JTAG, because the DebugPort does not provide JTAG." I would greatly appreciate any tips or assistance on how to initialize and execute the scan when connected through DAP.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
